# Second derivative test and continuity of $f''$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In the 8th edition of Calculus by Stewart, The second derivative test is stated as follows 
**The Second Derivative Test** 
Suppose $f''$ is continuous near c. 
(a) If $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)>0$, then f has a local minimum at c.
(b) If $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)<0$, then f has a local maximum at c.

I don't see why continuity of $f''$ is an assumption here.
Can you provide a function that discontinuity of $f''(c)$ affects the test?

Comment: The continuity of $f''$ is required so that in a neighborhood $I$ of $c$, for each $x\in I$ there is $d\in I$ such that $f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+\frac{f''(d)}{2}(x-c)^2$. You then use the hypothesis $f'(c)=0$, so that $f(x)=f(x)+\frac{f''(d)}{2}(x-c)^2$, and that $f''$ is either positive or negative near $c$ ($f''$ is continuous, so near $c$, the function $f''$ has the sign of $f''(c)$ by permanence of sign) to reach the conclusion $f(x)\geqslant f(c)$ or $f(x)\leqslant f(c)$

Comment: If continuity of $f''$ is required, can you provide an example that the test fails because of discontinuity of $f''$?

Answer (score 5):

The theorem still stands if you drop that assumption. My guess is that in your text, the assumption is needed for the particular proof that is shown. The theorem is stated and proved without that assumption in Edmund Landau's Differential and Integral Calculus.

Specifically it can be found in the Chelsea 3rd edition, 1965. Library of Congress catalog #60-8966. Chapter 10: Derivatives of Higher order; Taylor's Theorem. Page 125, Theorem 186.

Comment: Can you please provide the page and edition of the book? I have the first edition and couldn't find the proof.

Comment: sure, give me a few minutes, i will.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!